# p5 within IIFE, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

Tags: javascript, iife, p5.js

I'm trying to run p5 inside an IIFE but getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

It doesn't show up without IIFE.

**sketch.js**

```
var sketch = (function(p5) {
  setup = function() {
    p5.createCanvas(p5.windowWidth, p5.windowHeight);
    p5.background(0);
  };
}(new p5(sketch, "canvas")));
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.23/p5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  <div id = "canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a typo at the last line of `sketch.js`, it should be `})(new p5(sketch, "canvas"));`

Comment: That doesn't seem to resolve it.

Comment: Where are you trying to run this? OpenProcessing? Cause it works fine locally and on p5 editor

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a little weird. Why are you wrapping both the function and the call to `new p5()` in parenthesis? Also, you're missing a variable name for the `setup()` function definition.

Correcting all of that would look like this:

```
var sketch = function(p5) {
  p5.setup = function() {
    p5.createCanvas(p5.windowWidth, p5.windowHeight);
    p5.background(0);
  };
}
new p5(sketch, "canvas");
```

I also would not use `p5` as a variable or parameter name since that's the name of the overall p5.js library, so I'd do something like this:

```
var s = function(sketch) {
  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(sketch.windowWidth, sketch.windowHeight);
    sketch.background(0);
  };
}
new p5(s, "canvas");
```

More info can be found in [the p5.js GitHub wiki](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode).